# Is there a way to visualize all of the sources, targets, and channels in a Spring Cloud Stream application?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

As with Spring Integration, a lot of the work in writing a Spring Cloud Stream application lies in configuring the sources and targets of messages, as well as the channels that wire them together. That's also a major part of the work of maintaining and troubleshooting such applications, as well.

I'm sure some people are good at looking at YAML or properties files and visualizing The Matrix in their minds, but I am not.
Is there a way to produce a visualization of the sources, targets, and channels? I'm not talking about a transformed JSON or other formatted text view (in other words, **not** Actuator); I'm talking about a visual graph that makes it easy to ***see*** the connections and flow of messages.

It seems like all of the config data is there and available, has anyone integrated it with something like Graphviz or a Java graphing library? Looking for any experience in doing something like this, or a pre-canned solution.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration can be configured to expose the runtime wiring as JSON.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#integration-graph

See here https://ordina-jworks.github.io/architecture/2018/01/27/Visualizing-your-Spring-Integration-components-and-flows.html for a discussion about visualization.

Comment: Does that work with Spring Cloud Stream? I know that SpCS is built on top of Spring Integration but that's mostly an implementation detail that I, as a SpCS user, am unaware of.

Comment: It should, although you may find a few unnamed channels. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I finally got around to trying this and it doesn't seem to work. When I enable the SI graph controller, it returns a very incomplete graph (see https://gist.github.com/erizzo/40d1fb20294bfa5a65064ea83b8a5262). It's such a black box, I don't know where to start to troubleshoot. It would be nice to know if this is simply not compatible with Spring Cloud Stream (which would not be surprising since SpCS does so much magic behind the scenes to satisfy its obsession with convention-over-confguration :-).